# AS3 > Mouse Event not happening?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, mouse

**Background:** Trying to make a ball appear in the same location the mouse is positioned. Using Box2D Library. Working on a class file (.as)

**Issue:** The mouse event does not work (I click but nothing happens) . No output errors whatsoever. :(

**Mouse Event:**

```
   private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
            {
                sim.addCircle({x:mouseX, y:mouseY, radius:0.25, density:5});
                sim.start();
```

**Full Code:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    [SWF(width = 350, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  

    public class MouseTest extends MovieClip {

        public var sim:QuickBox2D;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function MouseTest()
        {
            sim = new QuickBox2D(this);  
            sim.createStageWalls();

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
        }

        /**
         * ..
         * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
         */
        private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            sim.addCircle({x:mouseX, y:mouseY, radius:0.25, density:5});
            sim.start();  

        }
    }

}
```

**Download Project** (BOX2D Included)

http://gabrielmeono.com/download/BOX2D-Mouse_Test.zip

Comment: What version of Flash did you use to create the fla? I couldn't open it with CS4. Anyway, I _think_ you just need to use `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked)` in your constructor instead of `addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked)`. Probably should also call `super()` on the first line of your constructor as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `addEventListener` in the class it only dispatches the mouse clicks that fall on the actual visual data inside that `DisplayObject`. If you use `stage.addEventListener` you can use the whole stage.

Answer (score 0):

QuickBOX2D uses meters instead of pixels. To work with pixels with this library, one must divide each number by 30. I simply added a "/30" to the mouseX and it worked! I updated my code for future reference.

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.actionsnippet.qbox.*;  
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    [SWF(width = 350, height = 600, frameRate = 60)]  

    public class MouseTest extends MovieClip {

        public var sim:QuickBox2D;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function MouseTest()
        {
            sim = new QuickBox2D(this);  
            sim.createStageWalls();

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _clicked);
        }

        /**
         * ..
         * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
         */
        private function _clicked(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            sim.addCircle({x:(mouseX/30), y:(mouseY/30), radius:0.25, density:5});
            sim.start();  

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should mark this as the answer then.